# Compilation error for set union

Tags: c++

I am getting a compilation error for this simple piece of code

"Error  1   error C3892: 'std::_Tree_const_iterator<_Mytree>::operator *' : you cannot assign to a variable that is const"

```
std::set<int> s1;
std::set<int> s2;
std::set<int> s3;
std::set_union(s1.begin() , s1.end() , s2.begin() , s2.end() , s3.begin());
```

I followed this page cant see what i did wrong.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/set_union/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The items in a set are effectively `const`. You can't change them in the set, because doing so might change their order with respect to other set members (which would violate the invariants). To modify an item, you normally remove it from the set, modify it, then insert the modified version back into the set (ensuring it's in the correct order when it's re-inserted).

At least if memory serves, the standard doesn't require that a `set<T>::iterator` be equivalent to a `const_iterator`, but does allow it, and your compiler apparently takes advantage of that.

In any case, what you almost certainly want is an `insert_iterator` to put the results from the algorithm into the set.

```
std::set_union(s1.begin() , s1.end() , s2.begin() , s2.end() , std::inserter(s3, s3.begin());
```

Answer (score 4):

`s3.begin()` needs to be wrapped in `std::inserter(s3, s3.begin())`.

`std::inserter` constructs an insert iterator which calls `insert` for you. 
However, a more efficient way than `std::set_union` would be:

```
s1.insert(s2.begin(), s2.end());
```

Unless you didn't want to modify `s1` and wanted a separate set.